# Getting element-wise equations of matrix multiplication in sympy

Tags: matrix, sympy

I've got 2 matrices, first of which is sparse with integer coefficients.

```
import sympy
A = sympy.eye(2)
A.row_op(1, lambda v, j: v + 2*A[0, j])
```

The 2nd is symbolic, and I perform an operation between them:

```
M = MatrixSymbol('M', 2, 1)
X = A * M + A.col(1)
```

Now, what I'd like is to get the element-wise equations:

```
X_{0,0} = A_{0,0}
X_{0,1} = 2*A_{0,0} + A_{0,1}
```

One way to do this is specifying a matrix in `sympy` with each element being an individual symbol:

```
rows = []
for i in range(shape[0]):
    col = []
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        col.append(Symbol('%s_{%s,%d}' % (name,i,j)))
    rows.append(col)
M = sympy.Matrix(rows)
```

Is there a way to do it with the `MatrixSymbol` above, and then get the resulting element-wise equations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, this question has a very obvious answer:

[`MatrixSymbol`](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/matrices/expressions.html)s in sympy can be indexed like a matrix, i.e.:

```
X[i,j]
```

gives the element-wise equations.

If one wants to subset more than one element, the `MatrixSymbol` must first be converted to a `sympy.Matrix` class:

```
X = sympy.Matrix(X)
X        # lists all indices as `X[i, j]`
X[3:4,2] # arbitrary subsets are supported
```

Note that this does not allow all operations of a `numpy` array/matrix (such as indexing with a boolean equivalent), so you might be better of creating a `numpy` array with `sympy` symbols:

```
ijstr = lambda i,j: sympy.Symbol(name+"_{"+str(int(i))+","+str(int(j))+"}")
matrix = np.matrix(np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(ijstr), shape))
```