# matrix multiply elementwise

Tags: sympy, matrix-multiplication

Is it possible to do from matrix_multiply_elementwise in sympy library with more than two matrices? Or any other way for multiplying couple of matrices elementwise?

p.s.
In numpy it is straightforward but since I need high precision calculation I decided to use sympy

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is the Hadamard product (or Schur product).

In sympy it is available as `sympy.matrices.dense.matrix_multiply_elementwise(A, B)`, documented [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.dense.matrix_multiply_elementwise).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It seems the syntax works only for 2 matrices and not more!

Comment: Yes, but you can do it nested. Or write a your own function which calls the Hadamard product multiple times. Or have a look as the source code of sympy's function: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/matrices/dense.html#matrix_multiply_elementwise It's extremly short, maybe you can use it to write your own Hadamard product for arbitrarily many matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to multiply three matrices elementwise.  The solution can be generalized to more than three matrices, or to functions other than multiplication.

```
from sympy import Matrix, pprint

a = Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = Matrix([[1,10],[100,1000]])
c = Matrix([[-1,1],[1,-1]])
x = Matrix(2,2, lambda i,j,m1=a,m2=b,m3=c: m1[i,j]*m2[i,j]*m3[i,j])

pprint(a)
pprint(b)
pprint(c)
pprint(x)
```

For simplicity, this solution is for matrices of shape 2X2, but it could easily be adapted for other sizes (using the shape property)

Here is the output

```
⎡1  2⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎣3  4⎦
⎡ 1    10 ⎤
⎢         ⎥
⎣100  1000⎦
⎡-1  1 ⎤
⎢      ⎥
⎣1   -1⎦
⎡-1    20  ⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎣300  -4000⎦
```

Answer (score -1):

You may have your answer on this post here: [Getting element-wise equations of matrix multiplication in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531244/getting-element-wise-equations-of-matrix-multiplication-in-sympy)

or here

[Sympy Documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.5/modules/mpmath/matrices.html)